# Normalize number according to exponential function

Tags: curve-fitting

I haven't picked up a math book in a while so please be patient. I have a series of numbers ranging from zero to infinity (realistically up to 10 though) and I want to normalize these values to 1 to 10 but the higher the number, the closer to 10 the normalized value should be. How would I go about customizing an exponential function to fit this use case and how do you limit it so it nears 10 but never reaches it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x) = 1 + 9(1 - (x + 1)^{-1}) = \tfrac{10x + 1}{x + 1}$ sounds like it fulfills your requirements:

```
  x f(x)
  0 1.00
  1 5.50
  2 7.00
  5 8.50
 10 9.18
 20 9.57
100 9.91
```

Whether this will actually be helpful for solving your real problem is hard to say without knowing [the context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl).

Comment: This helps tremendously, thank you! Is there a way to modify with `f(0) = 0` and not be as steep between 0 and 1?

Comment: @mart1n You said you wanted to "normalize these values to 1 to 10", so doesn't $f(0)$ have to be 1?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, I meant 0 to 10 but don't want to change the original ask since you provided a correct answer.

Comment: @Kodiologist thanks for your nice answer. Where the function comes from ? Is there a generalization for an arbitrary ranking that I may have ?

Comment: @Antoni I just used the fact that the reciprocal function has an asymptote of the kind the asker wanted, then adjusted it to get the requested 1-to-10 scale. You can change that range by strategically replacing the 10 and 1s.

Comment: @Kodiologist thanks a lot !! I guessed the 10 and 1 as the interval setting. The use of the reciprocal  was the missing part to me.